# Leaflet + GeoJSON and ArcMap : Map fails to load if missing variable

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, leaflet, geojson

I am working on my first web map using the Leaflet API.

I have a shapefile that was converted to the GeoJSON format (within ESRI's ArcMap software). The Shapefile contains a field attribute named **"Link_Ref"** which contains a string (web address hyperlink) as a value. **However, if there is a Link_Ref with no value (just blank space as the value) as shown in the attribute table in ArcMap, and then I export it to GeoJSON for Leaflet, Leaflet will fail to load and I get a blank white browser screen.** I see in the browser console the following error:

```
No value provided for variable {Link_Ref}
```

So, if one value is missing, it seems to keep my web map from loading.

I am trying to clean the data, but unsure how to proceed. **Will adding the text "null" to all the empty value fields allow my map to load?** A quick test of this failed to work.

Why do I get this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you're using in the Leaflet map?

Comment: I've found a fix since I last posted. Sorry I never updated this answer. Will do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a fix for now. I'm using the Mapbox API and it comes with mustache.js baked in. Therefore, when using the `L.mapbox.template()` function, mustache.js will skip over any blank values and finish rendering the DOM.